# How can I use the LatLng android class on an external server?

Tags: android, jvm

I have to transfer some functionality from the Android application code to an external server (REST). This code requires the use of com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng.
I was hoping I could use the com.google.maps.model.LatLng class, but they are not the same.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You cannot use a closed-source Android class on your server. You will need to find some other solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.